# Problemas com Header e footer em relatorio com mPHP

Tags: php, relatório, mpdf

Estou dando uma olhada no mPHP pra aprender a fazer relatórios com PHP, devido a um caso que ocorreu no meu trabalho, agora quero me precaver e aprender a usar tal ferramenta, mas estou com problemas(tentei fazer semelhante ao do trabalho).

Não consigo colocar header e footer no formulário, já tentei de várias formas que vi na internet, mas nada funcionou.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Cada variável que eu colocar aqui está no mesmo arquivo, só vou separar pra facilitar a visualização.

Código:

CSS:

```
$css="
    @page {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }



    #cabecInicial{
        font-family: 'Century Gothic';
        color: #3864B2;
        background-image: url('imgs/cabecalho_relatorios_1_grande.png');
        background-position: right top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 70% 120%;
        background-color: #efefef;
        height: 160px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #corpoCabecInicial{
        height: 115px;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    #dadosCabec {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 430px;
    }



    #corpoRelatCompleto{
        height: auto;//100%;//200px
        width: 100%;//1035    
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    .esquerdaEspaco10 {
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .subtitulo{
        font-weight: bolder;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .apertoDeMao{
        width: 154px;
    }


    .apertoDeMaoMini{
        float: left;
        width: 78px;
        margin: 8px;
    }

    #infoCabecInicial {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        font-size: 12px;

    }

    #obsCabec{
        opacity: 0.7;
        background: #144385;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        width: 230px;
        height: auto;
        color: #fff;
        float: right;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
        box-shadow: 3px -4px 3px 0px #336abd;
    }

    .textoFooter {
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        float: right;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .footer {
        background: url('imgs/footerGambi.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: right;
        clear: both;
        //page-break-after:always;
        //position: fixed;
    }

    .basicHeader {
        background-image: url('imgs/cabecalho_relatorios_1.png');
        background-position: right top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 70% 180%;
        background-color: #efefef;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        clear: both
        font-size: 12px;
        float: left;
        position: fixed; top: 0px;//page-break-after:always;
    }

    .textoCabecGeral {
        float: left;
        font-size: 26px;
        color: #3864B2;
        width: 500px;
    }

    #corpoRelat {
        margin-top:65px;
        font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
        font-size: 12.0pt;
    }

    .indice {    
        font-size: 22pt;
        border-bottom: 1px double;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .numeroIndice {
        padding-right: 15px;
    }

    .subIndice {
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

    .tabelaSistema {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }

    .tabelaSistema td{
        border: 1px solid #000000;    
    }

    .tabelaSistema th{
        border: 1px solid #000000;    
    }

    .tabelaSistema .tdLess {
        width: 15%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .tabelaSistema .first {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    #cabecTable {
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>"
```

;

footer:

```
$footer = '

            <div class="footer">
                <div class="textoFooter">
                    ********
                </div>
            </div>

    ';
```

header:

```
$header = '

        <div class="basicHeader">
            <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td><img src="./2016.07.12 relato_de_------.pdf_files/maoGambi.png" class="apertoDeMaoMini"></td><td>
                    </td><td><!-- textoCabecGeral-->
                        <div class="textoCabecGeral subtitulo">
                            RELATO DIÁRIO
                            <br>-------
                        </div>
                    </td><td>
                </td></tr>
            </tbody></table>


            </div>
        </div>
```

header da 1ª página:

```
$firstCabec = '

    <div id="cabecInicial">

        <div id="corpoCabecInicial">

                    <div style="height: 23px;"></div>

                        <div id="dadosCabec">
                            <table>
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td rowspan="2">
                                        <img src="./2016.07.12 relato_de_----.pdf_files/maoGambi.png" class="apertoDeMao">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="subtitulo esquerdaEspaco10">
                                        RELATO DIÁRIO
                                        <br>Gerenciamento do ------------
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="infoCabecInicial" class="esquerdaEspaco10">
                                        #-------
                                        <br>08/08/2016
                                        <br>-------
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </div>


                        <div id="obsCabec">
                            Principais ........ ++++++++ -----------.
                        </div>






        </div>

    </div>


';
```

corpo:

```
$corpo = '

    <div id="corpoRelatCompleto">


        texto totalmente aleatório gerado pelo Lorem Ipsum

    </div>




';
```

Juntando o HTML:

```
$pdfCompleto = $css.$inicioCorpo.$firstCabec.$corpo.$fimCorpo;
```

MPDF:

```
require_once ('mpdf60/mpdf.php'); 

$mpdf = new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header, "E");
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer,"O");

$mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252'; 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($pdfCompleto);
$mpdf->Output();
```