# Header e footer no mpdf não funciona por nada

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou com um problema com o mpdf e realmente preciso de ajuda.

Não consigo colocar o header e footer no relatório por nada, mesmo colocando `SetHTMLFooter` e o `SetHTMLHeader` não funciona.

Tentei a versão 7.0, 6.1, 6.0 e 5.7 e nada....

Não sou programador php, esse sistema caiu no meu colo.

Segue o codigo:

$CSS:

```
<style>

                @page {
                    margin-left: 20px;
                    margin-right: 20px;
                    margin-top: 15px;
                    margin-bottom: 15px;
                }



                #cabecInicial{
                    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
                    color: #3864B2;
                    background-image: url('imgs/cabecalho_relatorios_1_grande.png');
                    background-position: right top;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: 70% 120%;
                    background-color: #efefef;
                    height: 160px;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                #corpoCabecInicial{
                    height: 115px;
                    width: 100%;
                    float: left;
                    margin-top: 15px;
                }

                #dadosCabec {
                    float: left;
                    margin-left: 15px;
                    width: 430px;
                }



                #corpoRelatCompleto{
                    height: auto;//100%;//200px
                    width: 100%;//1035    
                    margin:0 auto;
                }

                .esquerdaEspaco10 {
                    padding-left: 5px;
                }

                .subtitulo{
                    font-weight: bolder;
                    vertical-align: top;
                }

                .apertoDeMao{
                    width: 154px;
                }


                .apertoDeMaoMini{
                    float: left;
                    width: 78px;
                    margin: 8px;
                }

                #infoCabecInicial {
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                    font-size: 12px;

                }

                #obsCabec{
                    opacity: 0.7;
                    background: #144385;
                    padding-left: 10px;
                    padding-right: 5px;
                    padding-top: 20px;
                    padding-bottom: 20px;
                    margin-left: 20px;
                    margin-top: 5px;
                    margin-right: 20px;
                    width: 230px;
                    height: auto;
                    color: #fff;
                    float: right;
                    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
                    box-shadow: 3px -4px 3px 0px #336abd;
                }

                .textoFooter {
                    margin-top: 20px;
                    padding-right: 15px;
                    float: right;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }

                .footer {
                    background: url('imgs/footerGambi.png');
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 50px;
                    text-align: right;
                    clear: both;
                    //page-break-after:always;
                    //position: fixed;
                }

                .basicHeader {
                    background-image: url('imgs/cabecalho_relatorios_1.png');
                    background-position: right top;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: 70% 180%;
                    background-color: #efefef;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 70px;
                    clear: both
                    font-size: 12px;
                    float: left;
                    position: fixed; top: 0px;//page-break-after:always;
                }

                .textoCabecGeral {
                    float: left;
                    font-size: 26px;
                    color: #3864B2;
                    width: 500px;
                }

                #corpoRelat {
                    margin-top:65px;
                    font-family: 'Tw Cen MT';
                    font-size: 12.0pt;
                }

                .indice {    
                    font-size: 22pt;
                    border-bottom: 1px double;
                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                }

                .numeroIndice {
                    padding-right: 15px;
                }

                .subIndice {
                    font-weight: bolder;
                }

                .tabelaSistema {
                    width: 100%;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    margin-bottom: 35px;
                }

                .tabelaSistema td{
                    border: 1px solid #000000;    
                }

                .tabelaSistema th{
                    border: 1px solid #000000;    
                }

                .tabelaSistema .tdLess {
                    width: 15%;
                    text-align: center;
                }

                .tabelaSistema .first {
                    text-align: left;
                    padding-left: 15px;
                }

                #cabecTable {
                    width: 100%;
                }

            </style>
```

$header:

```
            <div class="basicHeader">
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td><img src="./2016.07.12 relato_de_resultados_-----.pdf_files/maoGambi.png" class="apertoDeMaoMini"></td><td>
                        </td><td><!-- textoCabecGeral-->
                            <div class="textoCabecGeral subtitulo">
                                RELATO DIÁRIO
                                <br>Nível de -------------
                            </div>
                        </td><td>
                    </td></tr>
                </tbody></table>


                </div>
            </div>
```

$footer

```
    <div class="footer">
            <div class="textoFooter">
                VITEC - VP Tecnologia da Informação
            </div>
        </div>
```

$corpo

```
<div id="corpoRelatCompleto">


                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vel augue euismod erat hendrerit tempus. Nunc vehicula ex nec consequat efficitur. Praesent felis est, laoreet quis bibendum at, dictum sed tortor. Vivamus et magna at nulla egestas tempor. Phasellus at volutpat magna. In pretium sem egestas luctus porta. Etiam sed interdum neque. Duis a enim sit amet diam tempor efficitur at non magna.
                    </p> 
.......


</div>
```

codigo de geração de relatorio:

```
$inicioCorpo= "<div id='corpoRelatCompleto'>";
$fimCorpo="</div>";
$pdfCompleto = $css.$inicioCorpo.$corpo.$fimCorpo;

$mpdf = new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header, "O");
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header, "E");
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer, "E");
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer, "O");
$mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pdfCompleto);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Comment: só o header e o footer que não vão?

Comment: Não duplique a pergunta em outras [1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146551/91), [2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146233/91) vc pode editar ela a qualquer hora adicionando novos detalhes.

Comment: isso somete o header e o footer, o resto esta funcionando perfeitamente

Answer (score 0):

se tiver erro "Warning: Cannot modify header informati on " no functions.php
Deve alterar na linha 66 e 67 no arquivo includes/functions.php

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/&#([0-9]+)\;/m', function($m){ return code2utf($m[1],$lo); }, $str);

$str = preg_replace_callback('/&#([0-9]+)\;/m', function($m){ return codeHex2utf($m[1],$lo);}, $str);
```

Comment: Quando for adicionar código, formate-o selecionando ele e clicando em `{}` em seguida.